# 2-categorical constructions preserving/inducing Yoneda structures

Tags: ct.category-theory

I'm curious about how Yoneda structures on a 2-category $\mathcal{K}$ play with various 2-categorical constructions. For example, if I have a 2-(co)monad on $\mathcal{K}$, are there any conditions guaranteeing the existence of a Yoneda structure on the 2-category of (co)algebras?

Comment: I have the impression that for a lex-comonad T on Cat, coAlg(T) has a Yoneda structure. The same for a lex-reflective subcategory of a 2-topos.

Comment: I can believe that, thanks! I actually found Charles Walker's paper and it had the sort of results I was looking for.

Comment: Proposition 4.4. in Weber's paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.2652&rep=rep1&type=pdf says that you can find a discrete opfibration classifier for each fully faithful subobject of a given one. The entire paper describes a procedure to generate a YS on $\cal K$ out of a dopfib classifier $\Omega$.

Comment: Day convolution lifts the yoneda embedding for a monoidal category to a yoneda embedding in the 2-category of monoidal categories, and this formalises to liftings of yoneda embeddings of (co)lax algebras for well-behaved 2-monads T. Section 8 of [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04070) describes the case in which T extends to a double monad on an (augmented virtual) ``proarrow equipment''. For such T lifts of yoneda embeddings for colax T-algebras exist whenever T preserves composition of proarrows and both its unit and associativity cells satisfy certain Beck-Chevalley conditions.